# Issue Scraping "Cleaning The Glass" Table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to write code that allows me to scrape the shooting accuracy table from the basketball website cleaningtheglass.com. I've tried finding the CSS selector to extract the table, but I must have been doing something wrong because I kept on getting nothing.

Here is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://cleaningtheglass.com/stats/players?stat_category=shooting_overall#/"

# Read the HTML content of the webpage
webpage <- url %>%
  read_html()
  

# Use the specific CSS selector for the table
table_data <- page %>%
  html_nodes('#shooting_overall > div.stat_table_container')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the page is using javascript to create the table.  rvest by itself is not enough to do it.

Comment: Also, the document payload is encrypted with gzip encryption and must be decrypted before parsing the data. It's a lot easier to press the `<download this table>` button, download the data as CSV, and use `read.csv()` to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a somewhat interesting case. The reason why your selectors are not working are already stated in comments -- it's a JavaScript-driven site and what you see in CSS Selector or in inspector of browser's dev tools is quite different from the actual page source that is available for `rvest`. Though that table data is embedded in the site's source and delivered in a single response, that itself isn't too uncommon. But the size of that dataset is ~13MB and it's all squeezed into a single `<script> .. </script>` element; apparently `rvest::html_text()` is not able to extract all of it and returns a truncated string.

So instead of `rvest` we can load the page content with `httr(2)` and process lines of text; after locating relevant js function call, we can extract function arguments (JavaScript arrays and objects), each of those conveniently on its own line. Once those strings are clean enough (e.g. no trailing commas, extra whitespace is fine), we can parse those objects as JSON strings.

```r
library(httr2)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

url_ <- "https://cleaningtheglass.com/stats/players?stat_category=shooting_overall#/"

# read html as as lines
html_l <- 
  request(url_) |>
  req_perform() |>
  resp_body_string() |>
  read_lines()

# locate target js assignment and get get relevant vuePlayers() function argument values
idx_anchor <- which(html_l == "        window.vuePlayerFilter = vuePlayers(")
players <- html_l[(idx_anchor+1):(idx_anchor+4)]

# names from js function arguments
names(players) <- c("allPlayerData", "onOffTeamData", "onOffOpponentData", "statCategoryMappings")

# check start & end for anything that might cause issues for jsonlite
tibble(arg   = names(players), 
       start = sapply(players, str_trunc, 20, side ="right"),
       end   = sapply(players, str_trunc, 20, side ="left"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   arg                  start                   end                      
#>   <chr>                <chr>                   <chr>                    
#> 1 allPlayerData        "            [{\"th..." "...attempts\": 108}],"  
#> 2 onOffTeamData        "            [{\"cn..." "...hort_fg\": null}],"  
#> 3 onOffOpponentData    "            [{\"pt..." "...name\": \"Reath\"}],"
#> 4 statCategoryMappings "            [[\"of..." "...ve Rebounds\"}]]],"
# remove trailing commas 
players <- sapply(players, \(x) gsub(",$", "", x))

# parse all function arguments as JSONs
players <- lapply(players, jsonlite::fromJSON)

# looks like we have a view config for default table 
players$statCategoryMappings[[2]] |> str()
#> List of 2
#>  $ : chr "shooting_overall"
#>  $ :'data.frame':    8 obs. of  4 variables:
#>   ..$ abbr: chr [1:8] "efg_perc" "fg2_perc" "fg3_perc" "ft_perc" ...
#>   ..$ type: chr [1:8] "percent1" "percent1" "percent1" "percent1" ...
#>   ..$ name: chr [1:8] "eFG%" "2P%" "3P%" "FT%" ...
#>   ..$ sort: int [1:8] NA NA NA NA 0 0 0 0

# named column name vector for select
stat_map <- 
  players$statCategoryMappings[[2]][[2]][,c("name", "abbr")] |> 
  mutate(name = gsub("<br />", " ", name, fixed = TRUE)) |>
  tibble::deframe()
stat_map
#>              eFG%               2P%               3P%               FT% 
#>        "efg_perc"        "fg2_perc"        "fg3_perc"         "ft_perc" 
#>         ASTD% All         ASTD% Rim         ASTD% Mid       ASTD% Three 
#>       "astd_perc"   "astd_rim_perc"   "astd_nr2_perc" "astd_three_perc"

# and allPlayerData, subset that matches with the site's default table
# (total number of columns is 111)
players$allPlayerData %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(name, age, team = team_name, pos = pos_category, 
         sec_played = seconds_played, all_of(stat_map))
```

Result:

```r
#> # A tibble: 306 × 13
#>    name         age team  pos   sec_played `eFG%` `2P%`  `3P%` `FT%` `ASTD% All`
#>    <chr>      <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 Precious …  24.1 TOR   big        10311  0.509 0.548  0.267 0.778       0.815
#>  2 Bam Adeba…  26.3 MIA   big        26814  0.540 0.538  0.5   0.825       0.556
#>  3 Ochai Agb…  23.5 UTA   wing       16443  0.542 0.5    0.382 0.667       0.846
#>  4 Santi Ald…  22.8 MEM   big        12095  0.543 0.519  0.372 0.6         0.814
#>  5 Nickeil A…  25.2 MIN   wing       16807  0.565 0.6    0.364 0.333       0.774
#>  6 Grayson A…  28.1 PHX   wing       28936  0.627 0.5    0.474 0.864       0.705
#>  7 Jarrett A…  25.5 CLE   big        16405  0.622 0.622 NA     0.756       0.804
#>  8 Kyle Ande…  30.1 MIN   forw…      20847  0.579 0.612  0.222 0.581       0.535
#>  9 Giannis A…  28.9 MIL   big        27676  0.615 0.647  0.222 0.625       0.45 
#> 10 Cole Anth…  23.5 ORL   point      22301  0.5   0.478  0.351 0.848       0.484
#> # ℹ 296 more rows
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: `ASTD% Rim` <dbl>, `ASTD% Mid` <dbl>, `ASTD% Three` <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I am still newer to web scraping, so this is helpful for me. I will make sure to learn from this. Thanks again!

Comment: I am trying to scrape another table from another page on Cleaning the Glass. How can I reformat the code so that it scrapes 'https://cleaningtheglass.com/stats/players?stat_category=shooting_frequency' and 'https://cleaningtheglass.com/stats/players?stat_category=shooting_accuracy'?

Comment: We'll, you do need to go through the actual page source (view source or in the browser, NOT inspector/ CSS Selector) otherwise I don't think this approach would make much sense nor is generalizable to similar or almost identical problems.  Thogh the structure for those 2 looks exactly the same, down to the used JavaScript function, variable names and argument layout (one per line). What kind of issues did you run into?

Comment: It returns the same table as above regardless of the link. Most of the code you shared is with some functions and concepts that are new to me so I am still trying to fully understand what you did. Maybe once I understand it all, I will be able to determine what can be fixed.

Comment: Feel free to point out sections or concepts that seem confusing, instead of testing and reporting n+1 static variations of the same answer I'd rather extend it with some additional details on the current approach so it would be beneficial for a wider range of readers.  For example, are you comfortable with lists, subsetting with double square brackets `[[..]]` and apply-family functions? `players$allPlayerData` holds all the player data and for different views that site just selects a few columns for display, take a look at `View(players$allPlayerData)`  .

Comment: data.frames in `players$statCategoryMappings` seems to define a selection of columns in different views,  check it with `View(players$statCategoryMappings)`  browse through the list and you'll probably find a set that describes shooting frequency and shooting accuracy columns.

Comment: Ahhhhh got it. Thanks so much for the tip! I truly appreciate your help a lot. Thanks again!